# Sample a process on Mac OS X from a C/C++ program

Tags: macos, process, terminal, activity-monitor

The Sample Process feature in Activity Monitor is quite a useful thing. However, I need to do the same thing (take samples) of a certain process from another running process (C/C++) or a command line.

Is there any way to do this? I have been googling for this since a few days without any luck.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a command-line utility [`sample`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sample.1.html).

Example:

```
sample Safari -file /dev/stdout
```

It will get exactly the same output with Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 2):

There are some few commandsline application that come in handy: [`sample`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sample.1.html) and [`top`](https://web.archive.org/web/20100824082239/http://developer.apple.com:80/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/top.1.html).

If you want to write your own program, you can use the [`sysctl` system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysctl) to get such information.  However, it's quite tedious.

I would recommend installing [procfs file system](https://web.archive.org/web/20200816070829/https://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter11/procfs/) (built with MacFUSE).  This would create a new "directory" at `/proc` that contains a lot of useful information for each application (e.g. memory usage, cpu usage, locks, opened files, sockets, threads, etc).  The site gives a sample of how it can be accessed.  Then you can simply script your access to those files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will take a look at the other options that you gave.